# How to add a newline to PromptAttribute text?

Tags: botframework

I'm using a method to return a `PromptAttribute` for a `.SetPrompt()` call in my formflow dialog.

```
private static PromptAttribute CreateHappyWithAnswersPrompt()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);

    sb.Append("Are you happy with your answers? \n\n ");
    sb.Append("{&RegistrationNumber}: {RegistrationNumber} {||}");

    return new PromptAttribute(sb.ToString())
    {
        ChoiceStyle = ChoiceStyleOptions.Buttons,
        FieldCase = CaseNormalization.InitialUpper
    };
}
```

The issue I'm encountering is that the newline `\n\n` is not applied...

[image]

I've tried various combinations of `\n`, `\r`, `\n\r` etc and nothing works.

Is adding a newline for a prompt actually doable?

EDIT:

Using `sb.Append("Are you happy with your answers? " + Environment.NewLine);` results in the following...

[image]

Not quite what I'm looking for, as I'd prefer the newline to appear in the hero card.

Comment: Perhaps appending `Environment.NewLine` would work?

Comment: Close, but it's not quite rendering how I'd like. I've posted an image of what happens as an EDIT to my question.

Comment: Oh, actually, I think you can do `sb.AppendLine` as well. Hopefully that will work better :)

Comment: I get the same result unfortunately. As I can't set the format of the text e.g. to Markdown, as I can with a manually built HeroCard, it seems that's the reason I can't add a newline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `<br/>`

Otherwise try "..{Environment.NewLine}" where `..` are two whitespaces.

Comment: That worked. Hopefully it will work for other channels such as Slack, Facebook etc. But for now, in WebChat, it does the trick.